# How to load multiselect attribute values for current product

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have problem when I try to load multiselect values for product. I have:

```
$product->getSportTypes()
```

But these can give me only "sport type" Ids, not and names. How to get names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you want to display the value of the multiselect attribute named `sport_types` in the frontend. To do so you need to follow below steps:

```
$sportTypes = explode(",",$_product->getResource()
->getAttribute('sport_types')->getFrontend()
->getValue($_product));

foreach($sportTypes as $key => $value){
        echo $value;
    }
```

Comment: My Magento version uses an extra space for delimiter, i.e. ", " instead of ",". You might need that too.

Answer (score 4):

Better use:

```
foreach($product->getAttributeText('sport_types') as $type) {
    echo $type;
}
```

Amit already mentioned this but I want to make sure, that everyone understands, that getAttributeText returns you the attribute name for selects and an array for multiselects.

Comment: Much cleaner solution than the others. Thanks Fabian!

Answer (score 2):

Magento:

```
$product->getSportTypes(); give array of option ids
```

And below  give array of option

```
 $product->getAttributeText('sport_types');
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','sport_types');
 $collection =Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
                ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                ->setStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->load();
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($collection->toOptionArray());
                echo "</pre>";
```

For getting all Selected option  of shop_types attribute try below code

```
$Collection=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('sport_types'')->groupByAttribute('sport_types'');
```

Comment: These only works if only one value is selected, but if i select more, it will return false.

Comment: then what you want???want list all option of this attribute

Comment: I want to get all names from sport types that are selected

Comment: over all products or only this products

Comment: For current product, load sport types names as string